# Replace various duplicate values with np.nan within multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, replace, duplicates

I am trying to `replace` `duplicate` values across multiple `columns` in a `pandas` `df`. For the `df` below I have dates and values respective to these dates. All values are the same for each date. I just want to keep the first value for each date and replace the following `duplicate` values with `np.nan`. Below is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'Date' : ['1/1/18','1/1/18','1/1/18','2/1/18','2/1/18','3/2/18','3/2/18','3/2/18'],                 
    'Val_D' : [10,10,10,22,22,10,10,10],      
    'Val_M' : [100,100,100,100,100,240,240,240],                                   
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format= '%d/%m/%y')

pd.Series([10,22,100,240]).duplicated()
dup = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis = 1)
df = df.where(~dup,np.nan)

print(df)
```

Intended Output:

```
     Date Val_D Val_M
0  1/1/18    10   100
1  1/1/18            
2  1/1/18            
3  2/1/18    22      
4  2/1/18            
5  3/2/18    10   240
6  3/2/18            
7  3/2/18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one way is to simply use `diff`+`ne`

```
s = df[['Val_D', 'Val_M']]
df[['Val_D', 'Val_M']] = s[s.diff().ne(0)].fillna('')
```

Even though this yields your expected output, the `dtypes` of your columns become `object` and you lose your vectorization power with numbers. So I'd suggest you don't do that. Without the last piece `fillna('')`, you get

```
    Date        Val_D   Val_M
0   2018-01-01  10.0    100.0
1   2018-01-01  NaN     NaN
2   2018-01-01  NaN     NaN
3   2018-01-02  22.0    NaN
4   2018-01-02  NaN     NaN
5   2018-02-03  10.0    240.0
6   2018-02-03  NaN     NaN
7   2018-02-03  NaN     NaN
```

The `dtypes` are `float`. Now, with the `fillna('')` piece, you get

```
    Date        Val_D   Val_M
0   2018-01-01  10      100
1   2018-01-01      
2   2018-01-01      
3   2018-01-02  22  
4   2018-01-02      
5   2018-02-03  10      240
6   2018-02-03      
7   2018-02-03
```

with `object` dtypes.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `where` with `diff`

```
df[['Val_D', 'Val_M']].where(df[['Val_D', 'Val_M']].diff().ne(0))
Out[1136]: 
   Val_D  Val_M
0   10.0  100.0
1    NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN
3   22.0    NaN
4    NaN    NaN
5   10.0  240.0
6    NaN    NaN
7    NaN    NaN
df[['Val_D', 'Val_M']]= df[['Val_D', 'Val_M']].where(df[['Val_D', 'Val_M']].diff().ne(0))
```